# Move /tmp to RAM

Tags: mount, ram, tmpfs

I am trying to move `/tmp` to RAM and obey good practice:

- `/var/tmp` should NOT be placed in `tmpfs`, as it must survive reboots
- not mount `/tmp` as a stand-alone `tmpfs`, but rely on `/dev/shm` or `/run/shm`

However, things have changed between 2.6 and 3.2 kernels :

[Changes to the configuration and defaults of tmpfs filesystems](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=669726)

On 3.2 kernel, use `RAMTMP=yes` in `/etc/default/tmpfs`.

My question is: how can I achieve this goal with older kernels ?

My choice is nor to modify /etc/fstab neither this :

```
mkdir /dev/shm/tmp
chmod 1777 /dev/shm/tmp
mount --bind /dev/shm/tmp /tmp
```

Is there something like `RAMTMP` for 2.6 kernels ?

Comment: [`tmpfs` considered harmful](http://rwmj.wordpress.com/2012/09/12/tmpfs-considered-harmful/). Food for thought.

Comment: @sr_ Sorry, I strongly disagree with the linked article. `/tmp` can and should be used for temporary files, that's the whole point of it. `/tmp` is not supposed to survive a reboot (use `/var/tmp` for that) and who composes an email half the size of RAM+swap (without saving it)?

Comment: @Marco sure, I was just throwing in something I thought related.

Comment: More context: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/tmp-on-tmpfs

Answer (score 33):

You don't have to do all that, you can just mount `/tmp` as `tmpfs` by using a line like the following in `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs mode=1777,nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

You can also do it live (but bear in mind stuff that is currently in `/tmp` on your current filesystem will not be able to be accessed except through the inode and currently open file descriptors, so you should really do this by modifying `/etc/fstab` and rebooting):

```
mount -o mode=1777,nosuid,nodev -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp
```

Note that a `tmpfs` can swap. If you want a truly RAM-only filesystem, use `ramfs`.

Comment: Chris, my point is "best practices". The developers put native support to mount /tmp over .../shm; I read it is better to re-use the same tmpfs.

Comment: @Massimo My opinion is that the best practise is *not* to bind mount. It adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @Massimo Where are you finding this 'best practices'? The only reason I can see against mounting `/tmp` as tmpfs is because you now have 2 potential tmpfs filesystems that can fill up and use more memory (`/tmp` and `/dev/shm`). But if you're really concerned about filling up 2 tmpfs mounts, you can decrease the maximum size of the tmpfs mount.

Comment: @ChrisDown what is bad about bind mount? Also having a single tmpfs might make things simpler right?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Bind mounts are anything but simple internally, they come with quite a few unintuitive caveats that you probably don't intend (a particularly publicised one being the drama surrounding requiring remount for read-only mounts). Just use two `tmpfs` mounts instead.

Comment: @ChrisDown if there are 2 tmpfs will they compete with each other for ram? I read that tmpfs is normally 50%. So if there are 2 tmpfs, does that mean there are 2 tmpfs each trying to use 50%? In that case, should both be 25%?

Comment: Do the options `nosuid,nodev` really necessary? Do they exist by default? Perhaps some process would need it...

Answer (score 30):

`/etc/default/tmpfs` is for `sysvinit`, for `systemd` (Debian default since jessie) you only need to do:

```
systemctl enable tmp.mount
```

and on Debian Stretch or later:

```
cp /usr/share/systemd/tmp.mount /etc/systemd/system/
systemctl enable tmp.mount
```

See [changelog](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=787542#74)

Further details on RAMDISK/tmpfs can be found on the [SSD Optimization](https://wiki.debian.org/SSDOptimization/#Reduction_of_SSD_write_frequency_via_RAMDISK) Debian Wiki page.

Comment: Thanks! This is the right way to move /tmp to tmpfs in Jessie.

Comment: thank you so much! on gentoo i didn't understand why my /tmp is mounted tmpfs. the systemd script tmp.mount does it.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is rather old but in Debian-type distributions setting Set RAMTMP, RAMRUN and RAMLOCK in /etc/default/tmpfs (/etc/default/rcS or before wheezy) does the same job.

Comment: On **Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS**: `cat /etc/default/tmpfs` results in `cat: /etc/default/tmpfs: No such file or directory`. Do you have a link for setting this up? The answer is almost short enough (and vague enough?) to be a comment.