# is /tmp guaranteed to exist?

Tags: tmp

Do I need to check & create `/tmp` before writing to a file inside of it?
Assume that no one has run `sudo rm -rf /tmp` because that's a very rare case

Comment: What do you mean by "guaranteed"? The FHS requires it, so any FHS-compliant distro would have it. However, there are many special purpose distros that are not FHS-compliant. It's certainly possible to create a Unix/Linux distro without /tmp, but whether you need to care about that entirely depends on whether you care about supporting those systems.

Comment: Why not create your own temporary dir and delete it when you're done with it instead of relying on the next reboot to clean up?

Comment: @WGroleau I don't know about OP, but on scripts I write for my own system, I usually put temp files in a subdirectory of `/tmp` (created with `mktemp`) then remove that subdirectory on exit. Most of my system is mounted read-only and this keeps me from having to remember to `cd` to a writable directory

Comment: @WGroleau I'm not relying on reboots to clean it up. the `mktemp` looks really great, i'l probably end using that.

Comment: @Ayush Shanker: A good thing, too, because rebooting does not clean up /tmp.  Mine has files & subdirectories going back a year or so, since the last time I manually cleaned it.

Comment: @jamesqf Yeah, rebooting is not _required_ to clear `/tmp`. However, conversely it is _allowed_ to do so, and presumably WGroleau has extrapolated too far from that. My `/tmp` is a `tmpfs` held in RAM, so it does get cleared on shutdown. Still, that's just a detail of the system, which isn't guaranteed by the FHS. So, to the original comment, it's folly to rely on the presence _or_ absence of anything in `/tmp` between boots.

Comment: @AyushShanker you could always mount /tmp as tmpfs in RAM... https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55776/62481

Comment: Do not write directly to `/tmp`, use an os/environment supplied function, otherwise you're just asking for security/atomicity problems.  Read the supplied documentation for the function you use to determine whether you or the OS is responsible for cleanup.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The [FHS](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s18.html) mandates that `/tmp` exist, as does [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html#tag_10_01) so you can rely on its being there (at least on compliant systems; but really it’s pretty much guaranteed to be present on Unix-like systems). But you shouldn’t: the system administrator or the user may prefer other locations for temporary files. See [Finding the correct tmp dir on multiple platforms](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/174817/86440) for more details.

Comment: This is of course a design failure. `/tmp` is a name. `$TMPDIR` is another name. If you can't count on `/tmp` being the right name of the temporary directory, why can you count on `$TMPDIR` being the name of the right environment variable? Why shouldn't I check `$TMPDIRVAR` to get the name of _that_ variable? One level of indirection is sufficient, and  `/tmp` is exactly that. It doesn't say anything about the actual storage, it's just a name.

Comment: @MSalters there’s a bit more to it than that. Before namespaces, `$TMPDIR` allowed each user to have a separate temporary directory, or even to use different temporary directories for different programs; a single `/tmp` doesn’t provide that (again, without namespaces or something similar). There’s also a lot of history (or legacy) to take into account.

Comment: Per user is a valid point, but that is why a good design would use `~/tmp` for that. Which may still be the same physical location as `/tmp`, of course.

Answer (score 48):

In practice, `/tmp` is pretty much guaranteed to exist. However, even if it exists, that doesn't mean you should put temporary files there.

The [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03) convention is to use the `TMPDIR` environment variable. If it exists, it points to a directory for temporary files. If it doesn't exist, put temporary files in `/tmp`.

In a shell script, you can use `"${TMPDIR:-/tmp}"` as the temporary file location: this expands to the value of `TMPDIR` if it's set¹, and to `/tmp` otherwise. Or you can set `TMPDIR` conditionally in case it's unset, with the command

```
: "${TMPDIR:=/tmp}"
```

and then create temporary files inside `"$TMPDIR"`.

Note that any application can create files under `/tmp` or `$TMPDIR`. Furthermore this directory may be shared between users, so you need to take care about permissions when creating a file. Many systems (Linux, *BSD) have a command [`mktemp`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mktemp&sektion=1) which creates files safely in the right directory. It's generally a good idea to use `mktemp` to create temporary files and directory — especially from a shell script, where it's impossible to create a file securely in a shared directory due to the possibility of symlink attacks (`mkdir` is fine if you handle errors correctly).

¹  <sub>and non-empty — if the variable is empty then it isn't usable as is anyway, and it's generally a good idea to treat empty or unset variables in the same way if they're supposed to contain a file name.</sub>

Comment: Maybe you could mention that users have to expect file name collisions. So IMO the only recommended way to create files in /tmp is the command `mktemp` and this should also handle $TMPDIR" automatically.

Comment: This is the answer you want. I've seen systems without /bin let alone /tmp.

Comment: Also [**A.10 Directory Structure and Devices**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap10.html) states: *... The `/tmp` directory is retained in POSIX.1-2008 to accommodate historical applications that assume its availability. Implementations are encouraged to provide suitable directory names in the environment variable `TMPDIR` and applications are encouraged to use the contents of `TMPDIR` for creating temporary files. ...*

Comment: @AndrewHenle FYI beside `$TMPDIR` there are also other techniques to provide private `/tmp` directories per user or even per process (e.g. "Linux name spaces" https://blog.famzah.net/2014/06/04/private-tmp-mount-per-process-in-linux/, systemd based distros use that already). This should not change anything but you can not rely that `/tmp` is useful to share files between different users or services.

Comment: Just sad to find that `mktemp` is not in POSIX, although it's already in most popular operating systems like [GNU (Linux)](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mktemp-invocation.html), [OpenBSD](http://man.openbsd.org/man1/mktemp.1), [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mktemp&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-stable&arch=default&format=html), and [macOS](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mktemp.1.html).

Comment: Might be worth adding that `mktemp`-like functions are available in many scripting and programming languages, such as [libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Temporary-Files.html), [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html) and [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html).

Answer (score 6):

Although it's very likely to exist, you should check for another reason: it's not guaranteed to be *big*. On many systems, `/tmp` is backed by RAM rather than disk, and likely to be limited to a few GB. (On Fedora systems, it's half of RAM by default.) So, you should check not just for existence, but whether there's room to put whatever you intend to put there.

If you have something large, use `/var/tmp/`.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is "the Unix way" to check available space before proceeding, especially since it is not always known exactly how much space you will need.  In any case, you have to be prepared to handle a write error gracefully in case the filesystem should become full; and if you are going to do that, what is gained by doing an advance check that will be prone to false negatives and positives?

Comment: Depends how gracefully you can handle the failure case, I guess. The main point is to not assume that `/tmp` can handle large files. Let's say it's a 10GB download over a moderate-speed link. "Unix way" or not, it's pretty miserable to find out several hours in that it's not going to work.

Comment: @mattdm Checking early is nice but failure has to be handled. Maybe /tmp does have 10 GB available when the download starts but Another User copies 5 GB into there while your download is running. Now What? Heh.

Comment: Definitely! I don't mean this as an excuse to not handle failure.

Comment: "If you have something large" - use /tmp and let the OS swap if it needs to.

Comment: @UKMonkey Depending on how large. Many people don't have 10GB of swap, and very very few 100GB.

Comment: @mattdm and that would be a system that isn't set up correctly for that sort of program.  /var/tmp is for preserving data between reboots, not for large tmp files that you don't want to preserve.